# ui layout design stuck here

Tags: android, textview, ui-design

I  have two text-view with two colors

1. "qwer tyu iopasd fgh jkl zxcv bnm" and
2. "123456789"

I want to like to design the text view one after for example next to the "qwer tyu iopasd fgh jkl zxcv bnm"it display without any space"123456789" 
if the first textview go to about 2 to 3 lines then what to do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="qwer tyu iopasd fgh jkl zxcv bnm"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"` for `textView2`

Comment: @kumaand if the first text is too large and it fill upto 1 and half line then it not works

Answer (score 1):

i have given weight to both the text :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="qwer tyu iopasd fgh jkl zxcv bnm"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_weight="0.50"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>*
```

Comment: you can give background color also .... and if you want screen shot than i'll post it also....

Comment: you can also give background to textview

Comment: no it not working,i want to display it like qwer tyu iopasd fgh jkl zxcv bnm 123456789

Comment: if the first text view is about 2 to 3 lines then i want to show the textview2 in the 2 or 3 line where textview1 ends

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text view should show one after other in same row use the attribute in `LinearLayout`
`android:orientation="horizontal"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

if you want to add text view below other you should use the attribute `android:orientation="vertical"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

without margin and padding

**Updated Answer**
here is another solution

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="*" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/give_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="qwer tyu iopasd fgh jkl zxcv bnm"
    android:maxLines="3" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="123456789"
    />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: if the first text view is about 2 to 3 lines then how you apply this condition?

Comment: you can give max lines attribute in your textview give them 2 or three lines as you want other wise you can use table layout for this

Comment: if i have to use i will prefer to use tablelayout instead of linearlayout in your case.

Comment: it's not working when the first text value increses then it not working

Comment: try my updated answer i have checked it its working fine here